# IntelliJ IDEA not showing member field

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Problem as picture bellow, is there any option to enable showing member `abc`?

[image]

I am using IntelliJ IDEA CE 2017.2.1 with JDK 9+179.

Here is the sample code above:

```
    public class Test {

        @FunctionalInterface
        interface IF {
            String abc = "abc";

            void apply();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            IF theIF = ()->{};

            System.out.println(theIF.abc); // I can print `abc` value here, but...
            theIF. // DOT here(press ctrl + space) not show member `abc`
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't help but please suggest me good practice tutorials for Java 9.. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accessing static member with instance qualifier, and is better done as `IF.abc`. Therefore code completion doesn't offer it right away, but if you press Ctrl+Space second time, it should be suggested.

Comment: Another way to get this completion is by adding `-Dide.java.completion.suggest.static.after.instance=true` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options.